# Reuse the iOS Storyboard case

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

Im currently stucking in one case as follow:

First i created a view which have composing message function. The UI contain 1 message's title textfield and 1 message's body textview and Send Button. I called it ComposeMessageVC.

Outside, i have a list of messages, called SentMessageListVC, each message contain 1 Edit Button, the requirement is if user touched the button, it will push to the ComposeMessage view i said above with the title and body of the message are displayed.

Here is the code snippet for Edit Button:

```
func tableAdapter(tableAdapter: SentMessageAdapter, didEditMessageButtonClickedAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ComposeMessage", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ComposeMessageViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

And im considering put the data display logic in the viewDidLoad of the ComposeMessageVC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let date:NSDate = NSDate()
    let borderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let fromDate = NSDate().firstDayOfMonth()
    let toDate = NSDate().firstDayOfMonth().date(appendMonth: 2).date(appendDay: -1)
    messageFromDateButton.selectedData = date
    messageToDateButton.selectedData = toDate
    messageFromDateButton.dropdownLabel.text = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    messageToDateButton.dropdownLabel.text = toDate.toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    messageBodyTextView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    messageBodyTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    messageTitleTextfield.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    messageTitleTextfield.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

}
```

I succeeded in push the view, but still stucking in passing the data, can anyone help me to find out the way to do it.

Thank you so much and have a good day ahead.

Comment: How are you pushing the view?

Comment: Your question seems have nothing related to `Reuse the iOS Storyboard case`, more like how to passing data between viewcontroller, and this question been asked many times already

Comment: Hi @chitnisprasanna i just added the push view code above

Comment: In your code: The following line will return you the Instance of ComposeMessageViewController.
 
   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ComposeMessageViewController")
You can pass data as viewController.data = data, assuming you have dfined "data" property in the viewController

Comment: @Tj3n thank you, i will fix it, can you give me ur skype or any contact?

Comment: @chitnisprasanna i got ur point, but i still wondering where i should put the viewController.data = data in? In the EditMessageVC or in the ComposeMessageVC?. I tried to create viewController.messageTitleTextfield.text = "Hello", below the self.navigation.. code but it returned nil

Comment: What do you want to pass?

Comment: @Aisha I want to pass the content of the message like title, body..